# Is there a way to avoid while loops using pandas in order to speed up my code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm writing a code to merge several dataframe together using `pandas` .
Here is my first table :

```
Index   Values  Intensity   
  1       11      98 
  2       12      855 
  3       13      500
  4       24      140
```

and here is the second one:

```
Index   Values  Intensity
  1       21     1000
  2       11     2000
  3       24     0.55
  4       25     500
```

With these two df, I concanate and `drop_duplicates` the `Values` columns which give me the following df :

```
Index   Values  Intensity_df1  Intensity_df2
  1       11       0                0
  2       12       0                0
  3       13       0                0
  4       24       0                0
  5       21       0                0
  6       25       0                0
```

I would like to recover the intensity of each values in each Dataframes, for this purpose, I'm iterating through each line of each df which is very inefficient. Here is the following code I use:

```
m = 0
while m < len(num_df):
    n = 0
    while n < len(df3):
        temp_intens_abs = df[m]['Intensity'][df3['Values'][n] == df[m]['Values']]
        if temp_intens_abs.empty:
            merged.at[n,"Intensity_df%s" %df[m]] = 0
        else:
            merged.at[n,"Intensity_df%s" %df[m]] = pandas.to_numeric(temp_intens_abs, errors='coerce')
        n = n + 1
    m = m + 1
```

The resulting df3 looks like this at the end:

```
Index   Values  Intensity_df1  Intensity_df2
  1       11      98             2000
  2       12     855                0
  3       13     500                0
  4       24     140             0.55
  5       21       0             1000
  6       25       0              500
```

My question is : Is there a way to directly recover "present" values in a df by comparing directly two columns using `pandas`? I've tried several solutions using `numpy` but without success.. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Explore pandas `df.merge` function

Comment: rename the intensity column to Intensity_df1  Intensity_df2. then apply outer join . Refer this [link](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-merge-dataframes-in-pandas) (search for df_outer)

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1):

You can try [joining](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) these dataframes: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="Values")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I haven't mentioned that I will also merge more than two table, it can be 3 to 10 df to merge...

Comment: Where do these dataframes come from? How do you create them?

Comment: Theses, are datas from a analytical machine.

Comment: How do you create them?